# C++ - google protobuf

Tags: c++, linux, protocol-buffers, opensuse

I have downloaded and installed this framework :

http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/

I am using openSuse as operating system. I want to creat a soft link to the following libraries :

```
ln -s <PROTOCOL_BUFFERS_INCLUDE> include_pb
ln -s <PROTOCOL_BUFFERS_LIB> lib_pb
```

So basically I want the location of protobuf include folder and protobuf libraries.

Have anyone used this? Do you know where are this located?

Comment: By the way instead of symlinking you could run `gcc -I<PROTOCOL_BUFFERS_INCLUDE> -L<PROTOCOL_BUFFERS_LIB>`.

Answer (score 1):

The include directory should be: `/usr/local/include/google/protobuf` ...

The libraries should be `/usr/local/lib/`

However, this is on Linux Mint, 64 bit ...

Search for `libprotobuf*` on the usual library locations (`/lib`, `/usr/lib`, `/usr/local/lib`, `/lib64`, etc...) for the library...

Answer (score 1):

It depends on `configure` script `--prefix` option which defaults to /usr/local. To see all available options which can be passed to `configure` try `./configure --help` (from inside the directory).

Answer (score 0):

You can see the complete listing of the protocol buffer development package in [rpm find](http://rpmfind.net/linux/RPM/opensuse/12.2/x86_64/protobuf-devel-2.4.1-4.1.2.x86_64.html). The files you are looking for are in:

- include dir: `/usr/include/google/protobuf`, and
- library `/usr/lib64/libprotobuf.so`

I am not sure to the end of your endeavor. But if you just want to develop with it, then how about giving automake and autoconf a chance to sort it out for you ([tutorial](http://mij.oltrelinux.com/devel/autoconf-automake/))?